# query for distinct months in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a field of dates like "2011-06-30" in the database of my rails app. The dates could be be in a range of a few months. I'd like to know how to query using AR to find the distinct months in my database.

The results I want to end up with is something like:

```
[January, February, April, June]
```

Comment: what database? sqlite? mysql? postge?

Comment: development is sqlite but production will be postgres. I was hoping for a non database specific solution.

Comment: When you say you have dates like "2011-06-30", are those stored as *strings* in the database or are they stored as some kind of date/time field?

Comment: @Zabba they are datetime. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @Pierre but this is how I did it:

```
MyModel.all.map { |d| d.my_date_field.strftime('%b %y') }.uniq
# ["Jun 11", "Jul 11", "Aug 11"]
```

Answer (score 4):

not sure there's a pure AR way to do it.

with Postgre, you could do it like this:

```
Model.select("distinct date_part('month',your_date_field) as my_months").all
```

this would return an array like `[1,3,10]`.

You could then display the values of your array using `Date::MONTHNAMES[your month]` to have the full name instead of the number.

**UPDATE -- Based on Caley's comment, and probably more DB agnostic**

```
Yourmodel.select('distinct date_field').all.collect{|x| x[:date_field].month}.uniq
```

will give

```
[1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10]
```

If your data spans over 1 year, it means you'll be iterating over 365 element max. (366 in the bad years). So Maybe the performance hit is acceptable.
I've tried running this

```
(Date.new(2011,1,1)..Date.new(2011,12,31)).collect{|x| x.month}.uniq
```

And the result comes instantly

Comment: ```Model.find_by_sql()``` is also an option here as well as finding all months and calling ```.uniq``` although that isn't going to be as performant.